# How to refresh div when data coming to go template changes

Tags: kubernetes, go-templates

i am getting deployments list from kubernetes and displaying it in a div using go template.how to refresh that div when data coming to that div changes i.e., if i add a new deployment it should automatically be updated in the div without reloading.

```
<html>

<head>
  {{template "resources"}}
</head>

<body class="body">
  {{template "navbar"}}

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      {{template "homepage_sidebar" .}}
      <main role="main" class="col-md-9 ml-sm-auto col-lg-10 px-4">
        <div
          class="d-flex justify-content-between flex-wrap flex-md-nowrap align-items-center pt-3 pb-2 mb-3 border-bottom">
          <h1 class="h2">Services</h1>

        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="d-flex">
            <div class="align-self-end ml-auto">
              <button class="btn btn-success btn-md">Import <i class="fa fa-download"></i></button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>

          <div class="row">
            {{range $i,$j:=.ClusterNamesList}}
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="card rounded">
                <div class="card-header text-primary">
                  <div class="row">
                    <p class="d-flex mx-auto"><a title="{{$i}} bullseye view" href="/microservice/{{$i}}/">{{$i}}</a>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body" style="color: #343a40;">
                  <!-- <p class="card-text" style="font-size: 1rem" >Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. </p> -->
                  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                    <div class="row">
                      {{range $j}}
                      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
                        <i class="fa fa-check-circle" style="color: green;font-size: large;">{{.}}</i>
                      </div>
                      {{end}}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <br>
            </div>
            {{end}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi Pattapu, Could you add some sample code for how you go about generating the page at the moment? Updating a page in place usually requires some javascript and [AJAX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) polling for the data.

Comment: added example code above..please tell how can i auto refresh